# Enter recovery mode in headless ubuntu setup?

Tags: sudo, chmod

I know, there are lots of posts about this to enter recovery mode etc.
But I have a raspberry running headless ubuntu server, and sadly I have no keyboard or monitor to connect to it.

So what I did is:

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr -R
```

and now I face:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

Is wiping my server the best option if I don't want to run out and buy a monitor and micro HDMI cable?
I could get a keyboard from work, but if I can't see what's going on, I wonder if that would work.

So I have physical access, I just don't have the hardware to get into recovery mode as I understand it.

Comment: You didn't provide release details; but I'd likely remove the media & correct using another system (though you'll need a *like* system to get the file stat/attributes from; or backup of what was in that directory - as whilst most files have similar file attributes; not all will).

Comment: As you have figured out, it's dangerous to change permission on system files. Also, see my answer regarding KVM access.

Comment: Well, yes, I have a long way to go with Linux :) Thank you for the idea to remove and correct the media @guiverc, but I don't have a backup or any "like system". While I don't understand how I would correct it, I guess it won't matter. Or would it help if I took out the micro ssd plugged it in my Laptop and edited the files in nautilus?

Comment: Editing the files would change the contents of the file; that's not what you did - you changed the file attributes/stats using the `chmod` command; you need to return the 777 (1+2+4) back for each file to what it was... that value is what I'd have got from your backups, or a *like* system.

Comment: I see, well then it's settled, I will just start from scratch tonight. To be honest It's nothing much, just a Plex and SMB server with home assistant basically. Would you recommend going with 21.10, now that I have the chance? (I am currently on 21.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to enter BIOS/UEFI, Boot menu, Recovery mode, or other "special" modes on a headless server, you need to have some kind of virtual KVM (keyboard, video, mouse) connection.

Most "real" servers have an IPMI interface with a management LAN port that [provides this access](https://www.knownhost.com/wiki/dedicated-servers/how-to-access-ipmi), however a Raspberry Pi does not have this feature, so here you need something even more special.

One option is to configure another Pi as a IP-KVM, [like this](https://pikvm.org/). Jeff Geerling also has a [video about](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIrkEr2AeDY) this.

If you don't have a IP-KVM device, you need a physical keyboard, video and mouse to do anything outside a remote connection on a running OS (like SSH, VNC etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the idea with a virtual KVM, unfortunately I only own one Pi :)

Comment: Yes, then unfortunately you're out of luck with accessing the system without a keyboard and monitor.

Comment: All right, once again, thank you for your fast replies!